# Using type from F# host via Ajax in FunScript JS code

Tags: f#, funscript

How do I use types declared in my host project and served over Ajax in the generated FunScript code?

For example I lets say I declare a type T and then create a REST endpoint serving data in that format. Now if I want to load the data and use it from FunScript its no longer type T.

---

Edited with solution based on Alfanso's answer:

Assuming type "MyType" is defined in the base F# project and data matching this type served on localhost:6543/myData

```
let start () =
  async{  
    let url = "http://localhost:6543/myData"
    let req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    let! data = req.AsyncGetJSON<MyType list>()
    Globals.window.alert( (sprintf "%A" data) )
  }
  |> Async.StartImmediate
```

What I was missing was

- req.AsyncGetJSON
- Use Async.StartImmediate

Comment: I blogged in more detail about how I got this working based on the answer below: http://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2014/11/f-funscript-with-nancyfx-and-ractive.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please post some code to see better what you're exactly trying to do? For reference, you can see an example of how to exchange type-safe JSON values using FunScript.HTML extensions in this [little project](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro/PinkBubbles.Informa). In this case:

- Types are shared between server, client and database using F# records with `CLIMutable` and `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table` attributes: [Source](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro/PinkBubbles.Informa/blob/master/src/App_Code/Shared.fs)
- For the server, I'm using ASP.NET Web API which send types as JSON transparently: [Source](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro/PinkBubbles.Informa/blob/master/src/App_Code/Controllers.fs)
- In the client, I'm using the `WebRequest.AsyncGetJSON<'T>` extension from FunScript.HTML, which in the background just issue a `XMLHttpRequest`, parses the result with the browser `JSON.parse` method and uses `unbox<'T>` to "cast" the object to the desired type: [here](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro/PinkBubbles.Informa/blob/master/src/App_Code/Client.fsx#L34), [here](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro/PinkBubbles.Informa/blob/master/src/App_Code/Client.fsx#L52) and [here](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro/PinkBubbles.Informa/blob/master/src/App_Code/Client.fsx#L63).

`unbox<'T>` is the little trick you'll often have to use if you want to use dynamic types in a statically-typed manner in F#.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That sounds like it may be the solution. I'll try that ASAP and update my question with code so that it is clearer. Thanks for the direction

Comment: Perfect thanks for the detailed answer and code sample!